# Need an Excel-like grid in VB.NET

Tags: vb.net, excel, gridview

I am designing a program in VB.NET that can use an Excel-like grid. I want the grid to be able to handle merging and unmerging of cells. Suggestions?

Answer (score 4):

This Stack Overflow question contains some anserws which could be helpful:

[What is the best third-party WinForms grid for .NET?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/144338/what-is-the-best-third-party-winforms-grid-for-net)

You could try [Syncfusion's grid](http://www.syncfusion.com/products/grid/windows/default.aspx), which allows cell merging.

> Merged cells allow users to display
>   adjoining cells with like values as a
>   single cell. The merging is dynamic.
>   If a cell's value changes, the grid
>   will automatically adjust the merged
>   cells.

[alt text http://www.syncfusion.com/products/Grid/Windows/features/General_Features/images/gridmergedcells.png](http://www.syncfusion.com/products/Grid/Windows/features/General_Features/images/gridmergedcells.png)

Or the [XtraGrid (DevExpress)](http://www.devexpress.com/Products/NET/Controls/WinForms/Grid/):

> You can enhance data readability by
>   using the automatic cell merging
>   feature of the XtraGrid. When enabled,
>   neighboring column cells that have
>   identical values are merged into a
>   single cell. If a column is sorted,
>   cell merging has the effect of
>   grouping data - the number of cells
>   within the column will match the
>   number of unique values it holds.

[image]
<sub>(source: [devexpress.com](https://www.devexpress.com/Products/NET/Controls/WinForms/Grid/i/features/gridview_cellmerging.png))</sub>

Answer (score 1):

[SpreadsheetGear for .NET](http://www.spreadsheetgear.com/) is an Excel compatible spreadsheet component which includes a [Windows Forms Spreadsheet Control](http://www.spreadsheetgear.com/support/samples/windowsforms.aspx) which supports many [Excel compatible features](http://www.spreadsheetgear.com/products/spreadsheetgear.net.aspx), including merged cells.

You can download a free evaluation [here](https://www.spreadsheetgear.com/downloads/register.aspx).

Disclaimer: I own SpreadsheetGear LLC